# TYPO3 provider extension now showing its page layouts in Page Layout tab

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, flux, fluid

I am having trouble trying to select the Page Layout in my provider extension in the TYPO3 backend when I edit page properties and go to the Page Layouts tab.

My provider extension is overlaying on fluidbootstraptheme. I've done this before but for some reason I can't get it to work this time??? My provider extension's TS is included in my main TS template and CSS/JS assets are working properly... just not the Templates/Partials/Layouts. I have double checked my paths. Just this last piece to upgrade from TYPO3 6.2 to 7.6. Everything else is working and I don't see any errors anywhere else. I really thing this should be a simple problem.

**The environment: Upgraded FROM -> TO**

- TYPO3 6.2.0 -> 7.6.10
- fluidbootstraptheme 1.1.0 -> development (currently at 2.0.0)
- flux 7.1.2 -> 7.4.0
- fluidpages 3.1.2 -> 3.6.0
- fluidcontent 4.1.1 -> 4.4.1
- vhs 2.2.0 -> 3.0.1

**setup.txt**

```
plugin.tx_fluidbootstraptheme.view {
    templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_someexample.view.templateRootPaths.0}
    partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_someexample.view.partialRootPaths.0}
    layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_someexample.view.layoutRootPaths.0}
}
```

**constants.txt**

```
plugin.tx_someexample.view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:some_example/Resources/Private/Ext/Fluidbootstraptheme/Templates/
    partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:some_example/Resources/Private/Ext/Fluidbootstraptheme/Partials/
    layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:some_example/Resources/Private/Ext/Fluidbootstraptheme/Layouts/
}
```

**ext_tables.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'some_example');
```

**ext_localconf.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('some_example', 'Page');
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('some_example', 'Content');
```

**Layouts/WithSideBar.html from provider extension**

[Link to Gist of Layouts/WithSideBar.html](https://gist.github.com/Outdoorsman/0c761e42120ec3f91a3cd5d77fc9f82e)

**Templates/Page/WithSideBar.html from fluidbootstraptheme**

[Link to Gist of Templates/Page/WithSideBar.html](https://gist.github.com/Outdoorsman/98cf89d53df54058e2a4089f5768e423)

[image: Page Layouts]

[image: Static template added]

Comment: Without your custom extension the select box is present? Looks more like a fluidpages issue/configuration problem

Comment: Hello @minifranske, I have looked through many open and closed fluidpages issues now and don't see any more clues. To help you, I have now also included Gists of both `WithSideBar.html` files... maybe you guys can see something I can't as I'm not versed in fluidcontent/flux syntax. I should also be noted that before the upgrade to newer versions this was working properly.

Comment: When I do a builder fluid syntax check, `php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase builder:fluidsyntax --extension some_example`, I get the error, `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/example/public_html/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/Core/Parser/TemplateParser.php on line 499`

Comment: @minifranske I remove the some_example static template and the page layouts tab looks identical. When I include the some_example static template again it seems that there should be an additional option there like there used to be so I can select the page layout from some_example extension. What should I do to troubleshoot this???

Answer (score 1):

You may want to choose a template paths index value above 10 for your overlays in `plugin.tx_fluidbootstraptheme.view`. The default in Flux (and therefore fluidpages) is either 0 or 10 depending on which version you use - choosing a value above 10 lets you avoid any problems stemming from that.

Comment: Thank you Claus... I'm just following up after a long time and saying you were correct. All recent versions now start with 0, so to add additional overlays, starting with 1 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason that the Page Layout isn't working... can't explain why, but this solves the issue. *I will be happy modify the answer here is someone can elaborate why.*

SOLUTION: Make sure that your overlay files are not buried in subdirectories. As soon as I made the `Templates`, `Layouts`, and `Partials` folder immediate subdirectories to the provider extension it worked.

Instead of this...

**constants.txt (originally)**

```
plugin.tx_someexample.view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:some_example/Resources/Private/Ext/Fluidbootstraptheme/Templates/
    partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:some_example/Resources/Private/Ext/Fluidbootstraptheme/Partials/
    layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:some_example/Resources/Private/Ext/Fluidbootstraptheme/Layouts/
}
```

...change the path where the files are to this...

**constants.txt (modified Templates, Partials, and Layouts folder locations)**

```
plugin.tx_someexample.view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:some_example/Resources/Private/Templates/
    partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:some_example/Resources/Private/Partials/
    layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:some_example/Resources/Private/Layouts/
}
```

Now the overlay files are working for the time being.